# jQuery: Get the biggest number from classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

```
<div class="box1">
<div class="box9">
<div class="box4">
```

How can I get the biggest number from class which starts with "box"? **In this case I have to get number 9.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to iterate truth all div's elements and get class names. Then you need to store biggest values. I write simple example for you:

HTML:

```
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box9"></div>
<div class="box4"></div>​
```

jQuery:

```
var biggestNum = 0;
$('div[class^="box"]').each(function(){
    var currentNum = parseInt($(this).attr('class').replace('box', ''), 10);
    if(currentNum > biggestNum) {
        biggestNum = currentNum;
    }
})​;

alert(biggestNum);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/McJGQ/)

Comment: In most of te cases you can even skip .replace('box', '') part, parseInt will know what to do.

Comment: Only if the string is beginning with a numeric character, otherwise parseInt will result in NaN

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shorter implementation using jQuerys `map()` function and `Math.max`:

```
var nums = $("div").map(function(i, e) {
    return parseInt($(e).attr("class").replace("box",""), 10);
}).get();
alert(Math.max.apply(this, nums))
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sAFej/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Hiya another **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/26GYN/1/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/ktwDK/2/

To represent the class with largest number; it gets highlighted with red box. Rest demo will make it clear :)

**Jquery code**

```
var max=0
var maxClass="";
$("div[class^='box']").filter(function(){
    var result = /\d+(?:\.\d+)?/.exec($(this).attr("class").toString());
    if (max < result)
        max = result;

    maxClass = 'box'+max;

}).each(function() {

//dosomething!!          
});
$("div[class^="+maxClass+"]").css('border', '1px red solid');
​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box1">foobar</div>
<div class="box9">testsoo</div>
<div class="box4">hulkfoo</div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var classes = new Array();
$('div[class*="box"]').each(
    function(index, value) {
        classes.push(parseInt($(value).attr('class').replace("box",""), 10))
    });

alert(classes.sort().pop());
</script>
```

Whats happening is: 
a) create empty array
b) select all divs who have class box[something]

```
 $('div[class*="box"]')
```

c) get number from class name and convert it to integer

```
 $('div[class*="box"]')
```

d) put it in array

```
classes.push(parseInt($(value).attr('class').replace("box",""), 10))
```

e) sort array and pop last element (biggest one) to get max value

```
classes.push(parseInt($(value).attr('class').replace("box",""), 10))
```